# How do I get the "@" value of a DropDownList when updating a DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a standard DataGrid that looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView id="MyGridView"
    DataSourceID="MyDataSource1"
  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
  DataKeyNames="Id"

    Runat="Server">

  <Columns>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />


  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="IdState1"  DataSource='<%# GetCategoryNames() %>' DataTextField="State" DataValueField="State" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>
```

When updating the grid I have an UpdateCommand that looks like this:

```
UpdateCommand= "UPDATE [MauriceBlackburnOffices] SET [Name] = @Name, [Address1] = @Address1, [TheStates] = @State WHERE [Id] = @Id"
```

However the @State field is not recognized.

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@State".
```

What should the @ value be?

How can I get the DropDownList value into the update statement?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that you're using a SQLDataSource object to populate the GridView.  If so, you're probably haven't set the UpdateParameters ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updateparameters.aspx)).

Update your SQLDataSource as follows (you'll need to modify it slightly for your code):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
          id="MyDataSource1"
          runat="server"
          ConnectionString="MyDataConnectionString"
          SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table"
          UpdateCommand="UPDATE [MauriceBlackburnOffices] SET [Name] = @Name, [Address1] = @Address1, [TheStates] = @State WHERE [Id] = @Id">
          <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:ControlParameter Name="Name" ControlId="NameControl" PropertyName="Text"/>
              <asp:ControlParameter Name="AddressID" ControlId="AddressControl" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="Name" ControlId="StateControl" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
              <asp:ControlParameter Name="ID" ControlId="IDControl" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
          </UpdateParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this without the UpdateParameters

By carefully looking at the full source here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx I found the issue.

Its real wierd.

Where  I say:

```
[TheStates] = @State
```

"State" MUST be the SelectedValue value in EditItemTemplate and it must be attached by the "Bind" method.

Bind("State") creates @State.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="IdState1" runat="server" DataTextField="State" DataValueField="State" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
```